# ASP.Net page export to pdf

Tags: c#, export-to-pdf

I got stuck while exporting my ASP.NET page to PDF and it should prompt to user to save/open.

please help me.

Please tell me some free library and give me source code without using Crystal Report.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you got to the point at which you're currently stuck?

Answer (score 0):

[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is open source and will do that for you.

I've also used [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) before, which is free if you include a link back to their site.

There are a plethora of other options in this question: [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)